# Как вывести содержимое из файла *.txt на страницу html с возможностью редактированияфайла?

Tags: php

Подскажите какими способами можно реализовать следующую задачу. Есть .txt файл с несколькими столбцами допустим 4 столбца и 40 строк. Для удобства работы нужно отобразить .txt файл в формате .html (или *.php) и преобразовать в таблицу (сама структура *.txt файла разбита на таблицу уже) как только все ячейки будут заполнены то в этой таблице нужно дописать еще столбец и добавить на каждую строку select option , (Да , нет) как только будут выполнены какие то действия нужно будет сохранить изменения на странице и в *.txt файле. теперь подскажите в какую сторону копать, столкнулся с работой файлов впервые.

Comment: Читайте здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filesystem.php
PS. Насколько мне известно, данный портал не является местом для написания кода по вашему заказу! Другое дело, если бы у вас уже был самостоятельно написанный код и он работал не правильно.

Comment: @Uzgraph а я и не прошу писать за меня, мне интересно каким способом можно решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Основная идея состоит в том, чтобы прочитать файл, разбить строки на массив столбцов, из которых сгенерировать таблицу, а в конец каждой строки добавить необходимую опцию. В данном случае `select` лучше заменить на `checkbox`, я думаю.

Примерно это должно выглядеть вот так:

```
$columns = array("Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4");
$file = "some.txt";
$separator = "\t";
$lines = 0;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $fh = fopen(str_replace(".txt", ".new.txt", $file), "w+");

    while (isset($_POST[$columns[0]][$lines]) {
        $tmp = array();

        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $tmp[] = $_POST[$column][$lines];
        }

        $tmp[] = empty($_POST["opt"][$lines]) ? "Нет" : $_POST["opt"][$lines];

        fwrite($fh, implode($separator, $tmp) . "\n");

        $lines++;
    }

    fclose($fh);
} else {
    echo "<form action="myform.php" method="post">;
    echo "<table>";

    echo "<th><td>#</td>";
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        printf("<td>%s</td>", $column);
    }
    echo "<td>Да / Нет</td></th>";

    foreach (file($file) as $line) {
        $tds = preg_split("#" . preg_quote($separator) . "+#", trim($line));

        printf("<tr><td>%d</td>", $lines + 1);

        foreach (array_combine($columns, $tds) as $column => $td) {
            printf('<td><input type="text" name="%s[%d]" value="%s"></td>', $column, $lines, htmlentities($td));
        }

        printf('<td><input type="checkbox" name="opt[%d]" value="Да"></td></tr>', $lines++);
    }

    echo '</table><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
}
```